# Selenium Script Fails When Split Into Functions and Classes for Opera WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, opera

I am working on an automation script using Selenium and Python. I want to automate some activities on Instagram and check some IP-related info. The automation script needs to run on the Opera web browser.

Initially, I was running my script in a single file without functions and classes and it worked fine. However, when I tried to split it into functions and classes for better code structure and readability, it started crashing.

The error messages I'm seeing are as follows:

```
[ERROR] Error opening link: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=65032): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/252d00b6bf664f61d5fb0d6452bff83f/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001E872646010>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

I also noticed some console errors, but I'm not sure if they are related:

```
[ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."
```

Here's how I have it in the all-in-one version where it doesn't crash:

```
webdriver_service = service.Service(CONFIG['web_driver']['driver_path'])
webdriver_service.start()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = CONFIG['web_driver']['binary_location']
options.add_experimental_option('w3c', True)
options.add_extension("./3.4.8_0.crx")
options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={CONFIG['web_driver']['user_data_path']}")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Remote(webdriver_service.service_url, options=options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

In the other version, the code is divided into two main parts: app.py where the main logic resides, and selenium_manager.py where I have abstracted out the Selenium-related functions.

app.py:

```
class MainApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.selenium_manager = SeleniumManager(logger, CONFIG["web_driver"])
        self.driver = self.selenium_manager.open_link("https://www.google.com/")
        
    def check_ip(self):
        ...
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_app = MainApp()
    time.sleep(30)
    main_app.check_ip()
    time.sleep(30)
    main_app.selenium_manager.quit()
```

and selenium_manager.py:

```
class SeleniumManager:
    def __init__(self, logger, web_driver_settings):
            self.logger = logger
            self.logger.info("Initializing Selenium driver...")
            
            webdriver_service = service.Service(web_driver_settings["driver_path"])
            webdriver_service.start()

            
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            
            options.binary_location = web_driver_settings["binary_location"]
            options.add_experimental_option('w3c', True)
            options.add_extension("...path-to-extension")
            options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={web_driver_settings['user_data_path']}")
            options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
            options.headless = web_driver_settings["headless"]


            self.driver = webdriver.Remote(webdriver_service.service_url, options=options)
            self.driver.maximize_window()
            
            self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, web_driver_settings["wait_time"])
            
            self.logger.info("Selenium driver initialized successfully!")


    def quit(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.logger.info("Selenium driver closed successfully!")

    def open_link(self, href):
        try:
            self.driver.get(href)
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f"Error opening link: {e}")


    .....
```

1. **What could be causing this error and how do I fix it?**
2. **Is it something related to the fact that I'm using Opera?**
3. **Should I consider using another browser? Is there another automation framework that works well with Opera?**